# 460439 put on hold and then closed without explanation?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

My recent question, [Read address from MSI Capability Structure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460439/read-address-from-msi-capability-structure), was first put on hold as unclear then closed. With respect to the question requirements:

- The answer to this specific question definitely does not exist somewhere else
- It is related to driver development for the linux kernel
- The question is very specific. I am asking for a way to determine either the location of the MSI capability structure associated with a particular interrupt or the address located therein.
- It is related to a general feature of the PCI standard, so it may be relevant to others

I even left a comment on the question while it was still on hold asking for clarification while it was still on hold, with no luck. I found the answer I was looking for and want to post it, but with it closed I can't.

Could someone shed some light on any problem(s) with my question and what I should avoid in the future to prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 3):

Your question was closed as unclear. Looking at it, probably a more valid reason to close this is simply that it's off-topic on this website. I had to look up MSI not knowing if it was MSI (Microsoft installer related) or something else. Apparently it's the something else, I'm familiar with the PCI spec and to my knowledge we've never answered any question such as this on Unix & Linux.

I'm kind of hard pressed to figure out where I'd direct this question as well. Possibly one of these:

- https://superuser.com/
- https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Might fit into one other site, possibly even https://stackoverflow.com/. But it definitely doesn't seem like it would fit here.

At any rate, we can migrate it to any of the other sites, let me know and we can move it to whichever site you feel is a better fit.

Comment: I understand that it is a rather obscure topic, but I did edit my question to provide reference to what I was referring to.

In either case, I also was not sure about whether this was the right place for this. Perhaps I could have clarified further, I am looking for a kernal function to provide this information, which I did end up finding. So it would either be here or stackoverflow, but I felt that this site would be more relevant to the question. Still, I want to help anyone else in the future with the issue so I will leave it to you to decide what should be done.

Comment: @CainRose imho did put this on SO. Lmk and I can move it.

Comment: sure, if you could move it, that'd be great

Comment: @CainRose - FYI it was migrated.